# grep / awk optimsed output of netstat or ss

Tags: awk, grep

I am trying to write a bash script that outputs TCP connections that are established on port 8000 (icecast) and also filter an internal IP address from that list.

Here is 2 examples that work but I need help optimising the command line.

1.

```
    netstat -ant | grep 8000 | grep ESTABLISHED | grep -v
'192.168.1.102
```

2.

```
    ss -H -nt sport eq 8000 | awk '{print $5}'| awk -F':' '{print $1}' |
    grep -v '192.168.1.102'
```

Can someone help me combine the `grep` or `awk` filters please? From what I have read the SS command is better in performance than the `netstat` command. But if someone knows a better application to get the above information and filter it then I will use that instead.

Sample output from SS:

```
ESTAB       0      1400   192.168.3.2:8000               x.x.x.x:62090
```

ESTAB       0      0      192.168.3.2:8000               192.168.1.102:1033

Sample from netstat:

```
    tcp        0   1400 192.168.3.2:8000        x.x.x.x:62090       ESTABLISHED
    tcp        0   0    192.168.3.2:8000        192.168.1.102:1033  ESTABLISHED
    tcp        0   0    192.168.3.2:22          y.y.y.y:32897       ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please post sample of input(sample of output of your netstat command) and final sample expected output in CODE TAGS, use `{}` button for same and let us know then.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, instead of adding details here in the comments (where as you will notice they are not very readable or useful anyway).

Comment: To be honest still not clear. Please keep it simple and try to add  more details in simple manner like I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: You should generally ask a single question only, and show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, Awk can do everything `grep` can do, and usually almost as fast. As a general guidance, try to minimize the number of processes.  Thus, try to refactor all your pipelines into just a single Awk program.

1. You'll want to escape the dots in the IP address, too.

   ```
   netstat -ant | awk '/8000/ && /ESTABLISHED/ && ! /192\.168\.1\.102/'
   ```
2. This is a little bit more challenging, but by no means complicated.

   ```
   ss -H -nt sport eq 8000 |
   awk '{ split($5, a, /:/); if (a[1] !~ /192\.168\.1\.102/) print a[1] }'
   ```

Comment: option 2 is what i've gone for.

Comment: `a[1] != "192.168.1.102"` would be more concise and more robust (just in case something could be in there that has leading/trailing chars) in this case.

Comment: That's proprably a correct observation; I very directly translated the code so I would not introduce any new assumptions.